# Is Dauhitru (Daughter's son) allowed to be a bhokta at annual Shraddha?

Tags: belief, rituals, dharma-shastras, sraddha

My maatulah (maama, mother's brother) is performing annual Shraddha of my maternal grand father and he invited me to take part in the Shraddha as a bhokta.

**Is Dauhitru (Daughter's son) allowed to be a bhokta at annual Shraddha?**

Any Shastra pramana will be hugely helpful.

Added to this
My mother will also be there at the ceremony. At the end of the ceremony, it is customary for everyone to prostrate to all the bhoktas to get the blessings. If I take part then my mother has to do namaskaram to me which in whole is prohibited in Shastra.

**Can mother prostrate to the son at specific position, in this case a bhokta?**

Can someone please enlighten me?

Comment: Other relationships doesn't matter. Shastras allows that. Father can prostrate before the son who has taken sanyasa but mother is treated supreme. @Vivkta edit is not right. I am reverting the change.

Comment: For a Sanyasi the concept of material Mother & Father is a moot point.

Comment: @Palpatine, Shastras take different stance w.r.t mother. Bhagavatpada showed the way. Palimaaru mutt swami also showed this very recently. https://starofmysore.com/palimar-mutt-seer-sri-vidyadheesha-theertha-swamiji-ascends-paryaya-peetha-udupi/

Answer (score 3):

As per [Southern Recension of Mahabharata: Adi Parva: Chapter 87](https://sanskritdocuments.org/mirrors/mahabharata/mbhK/mahabharata-k-01-sa.html),

> त्रीणि श्राद्धे पवित्राणि दौहित्रः कुतपस्तिलाः॥ 1-87-29

The rough English translation of this would be **Three things are considered pure in Shraddha, दौहित्र (daughter's son), कुतप (दिवसस्याष्टमे भागे 8th muhurta of the day), and तिल (sesamum-seeds)**.

There is an interesting [story](https://archive.org/details/AXSM_mahabharata-part-1-gita-press-gorakhpur/page/n308/mode/1up) related to this shloka (given in same and previous chapters). King Yayati (father of Yadu [ancestor of Yadavas: Vrishnis, Andhakas etc], and Puru [ancestor of Paurvas: Kaurvas, Pandavas etc]) was thrown down from heaven after his virtues exhausted. When he was thrown from heaven he requested gods that he should fall in virtuous men. Then, he was thrown where Ashtaka, Shibi, Pratardana and Vasumana were doing a yajna. These all were great kings who retired to forest and they all were sons of Madhavai (Yayati's daughter). They all donated their virtues and king Yayati was sent to heaven again and these four kings also ascended to heaven along with Yayati. Then, Yayati said that going forward daughter's sons would be considered pure in Shraddha.

---

This shloka is found in [Vishnu Purana: Book III: Chapter 15](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp089.htm) with slight variation:

> Three things are held pure at obsequies, a daughter's son, a Nepal blanket, and sesamum-seeds 15;

The same chapter of Vishnu Purana describes who are to be entertained at Śráddhas:

> AURVA proceeded.--"Hear next, oh prince, what description of Brahman should be fed at ancestral ceremonies. he should be one studied in various triplets of the Rich and Yajur Vedas 1; one who is acquainted with the six supplementary sciences of the Vedas 2; one who understands the Vedas; one who practises the duties they enjoin 3; one who exercises penance; a chanter of the principal Sáma-veda 4, an officiating priest, a sister's son, **a daughter's son**, a son-in-law, a father-in-law, a maternal uncle, an ascetic, a Brahman who maintains the five fires, a pupil, a kinsman; one who reverences his parents. A man should first employ the Brahmans first specified in the principal obsequial rite; and the others (commencing with the ministering priest) in the subsidiary ceremonies instituted to gratify his ancestors.

So, daughter's son is allowed in Shraddha in fact they are recommended and considered as important and pure as तिल (sesamum-seeds).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, allowed.

See some relevant verses from the Manu Smriti:

> 3.146. If one of these three dines, duly honoured, at a funeral sacrifice, the ancestors of him (who gives the feast), as far as the
> seventh person, will be satisfied for a very long time.
>
> 3.147. This is the chief rule (to be followed) in offering sacrifices to the gods and manes; know that the virtuous always observe the
> following subsidiary rule.
>
> 3.148. **One may also entertain** (on such occasions) one’s maternal grandfather, a maternal uncle, a sister’s son, a father-in-law, one’s
> teacher, **a daughter’s son**, a daughter’s husband, a cognate
> kinsman, one’s own officiating priest or a man for whom one offers
> sacrifices.